# Displaying Json data without key in handlebar.js

Tags: javascript, html, json, handlebars.js

```
 {
   "Relation":[
     [1,"one"],
     [2,"two"],
     [3,"Three"],
     [4,"Four"]
   ]
 }
```

I want to display only numbers in words and not actual number using handlebars.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of `helpers` in `Handlebars` like this: http://jsfiddle.net/sandenay/2hg9qcdL/1/

HTML:

```
 <div class="body">
   {{#Relation}}
     {{#getword this}}{{/getword}}
   {{/Relation}}
</div>
```

Helper:

```
 Handlebars.registerHelper('getword', function(a,opts) {


        return (a[1]);

    });
```

Comment: Thank you very much. It worked according to my need.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate over your object and create a separate array:

```
var values = []
obj.Relation.forEach(function(el){
    values.push(el[1]);
});
console.log(values); // ["one", "two", "Three", "Four"]
```

Comment: This was good answer but I wanted to integrate that with handlebar.js